# Find the reverse of a number in the way that the number hundred place number should be in the unit place in Python. [Eg: 1234 should print as 4312]

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: code 1]

I am getting output as 4321 but it should print 4312 in Python

[image: code 2]

Comment: Please post your code as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: Why should it return 4312 rather than 4321 ?

Comment: @zwitsch, The requirement is the number which is present at hundred place should come to units place after reversal.

Comment: @TheThonnu, Noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remain in your philosophy, it would be enough to stop the loop as soon as n drops below 100 then append n to rev:

```
n = 1234
rev = 0

while n > 100:
    a = n % 10
    rev = rev * 10 + a
    n = n // 10

rev = rev*100 + n

print(rev)  // 4312
```

Comment: Thanks the code is working fine and i understood how it works now by your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This code reverses a number. you want to create a new digit such that:

....+10b+a -> ....+10a+b

so you should subtract result from 9b-9a :

```
def reverse(n):
    x = int(0)
    while(n>0):
        x=x*10 + n%10
        print(x)
        n=int(n/10)
    return x

n=1234;
print(n)
n = reverse(n)
print(n)
a = int(n % 10);
b = int(((n % 100) - a) / 10)
print(n-9*b+9*a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This method may help:

```
n = 1234
rev = list(reversed(str(n)))
rev[-1], rev[-2] = rev[-2], rev[-1]
rev = int("".join(rev))
```

*Edit: replacement of `[0]` and `[1]` to `[-1]` and `[-2]` as per @zwitsch's recomendation*

Comment: This code is printing the result as 3421. But it suppose to print 4312

Comment: Guess it should be -1 an -2 rather than 0 and 1.

Comment: Yep, that would probably be the necessary fix